# Angular 11 directive Change directive tag

Tags: angular

Angular 11 directive Change directive tag

selector: [changeTagDirective]

*Is posible to change html tag with a directive?*
inside my tag **i have translateService** Pipe i want to keep them in the result html.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you elaborate?

Comment: Would it still be a valid case for you to have `div` with `changeTagDirective` applied on and the result is having a nested element with the desired tag you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i found a solution creating an Input named Tag: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' ..
Then in afterVeiewInit hook i create a new element with that tag and finaly append  all childNodes of parent element that contains the directive. I need use setTimeOut or asapScheduler because Renderer2.appendChild can't be in a loop. It works